# Powershell - GET JSON response from REST API, update a property and then PUT JSON to same API?

Tags: json, powershell, rest

I am creating a Powershell script for a user that downloads a JSON object from our REST API, updates a value, then updates the API with the new version of the object. I cannot get this to work, our API either reports that the body is empty or malformed.

This is an example of the code that I am using:

```
$headers = @{
  "Accept" = "application/json"
}
$settings = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($apiUrl)/settings" -Method Get -Headers $headers

$settings.name = "Hello World!"

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = $token
  "Accept"        = "application/json"
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($apiUrl)/settings" -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $settings -ContentType "application/json"
```

When done like this, the API reports that the body is empty. If I try to use ConvertTo-JSON, the API reports that the body is malformed.

I need to use Powershell, as this script is run by another service that can only use Powershell scripts. The target machine is running Powershell 7.3.3.

Comment: To download you use an HTTP Request and got an HTTP Response.  The normal status returned in a HTTP Header is 200 OK.  When an error occurs the status normally is a 400 or 500 error.  You are probably getting an error an need to check the error status.   The other possibility is HTTPS (secure) the TLS failed, but this would not return an empty response.  When TLS fails you do not get a response and error are generated by a timeout when no response is received.

Comment: I have live access to the API, I'm sending responses both to a remote version as well as one running on the same machine as my script so I can inspect the contents. Logs from my API code show the request body as either empty, or a middleware I'm using throws an exception indicating the data is malformed. I tried to inspect the request with Fiddler and WireShark but I couldn't see it unfortunately, so I don't know what Powershell is actually sending.

Comment: As a test you could try ```$settings | ConvertTo-Json``` to confirm the body looks correct, and maybe try to post *that* using fiddler / postman to double-check it’s valid.

Comment: You need to verify if body is empty or malformed.  Empty usually means there was an error and the status would indicate the failure.  Malformed usually means the format of the response is different than expected like xml instead of json.  But could mean the server has a bug.  Fiddler and wireshark will not see the body if response is HTTPS (secure, encrypted).  You can get body by just reading the response body property.  The body could be gzip (compressed) and that is why you are getting error.

Comment: I changed my debugging mechanism and re-read the docs, and was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by re-converting the modified response to JSON with some specific parameters like so:

```
$settings = ConvertTo-Json $settings -Depth 100 -Compress -EscapeHandling EscapeNonAscii
```

My API only consumes JSON bodies, but `Invoke-RestMethod` automatically converts to `PSObject`. I had to convert the object to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`, but by default the depth is too low, and the JSON parser will incorrectly escape special characters and add whitespace that my API cannot consume, hence the other flags are required.